# Quicktime (.mov) video blob to audio in JavaScript (Mobile Safari)?

Tags: mobile-safari, wav, quicktime, .mov

I am trying to work around the restrictions on Mobile Safari on uploading files via HTML 5 forms.

According to the research I've done so far, Mobile Safari (iOS 9+) doesn't allow you to specify audio only for file uploads, but it does allow video.

My workaround is to get a video from the user as a blob, and then send the blob to my server and extract the audio as a .wav using ffmpeg.

Unfortunately, the video files are quite big (1min=30meg), and the equivalent audio is much smaller (1min=6meg)

Obviously it's much more preferable to only send the audio to the server.

Does anyone know a method of extracting audio from video on the *client* side in Mobile Safari? I know this is a long shot, but thought it was worth asking.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nope.. until Apple properly adopts HTML5 standards in Mobile Safari, it's a losing battle.. :-(

Comment: How unfortunate. I looked into this too and came to the same conclusion. I would have loved to ease the load on the server by being able to do this on the client. Thank you for answering.